# How to prevent user to go back with right click on back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

When I press and hold the browser back button or just right click the back button I can go back pages. But I need to disable it. Is there any way to do that with javascript or jsp

Comment: there's no real way of disabling it using the page's contents, and from a UX perspective, it's a bad idea.

Comment: It should be do-able with the [HTML5 history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), but I agree with Timothy: I hate websites that fiddle with my browser history or prevent me from doing something so basic!

Comment: Why You need this? Can't You make a Single Page Application?

Comment: "But I need to disable it." — You're addressing the wrong problem. Fix things so the server doesn't care if the user revisits a previous page instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Open A New Window without Back Button**

browser-back-button-viralpatelThis one is very crude technique. But in some case it works like charm. All you have to do is to open the webpage in a new window. This window doesn’t have back button at all because we have hide the toolbar.
This technique does work in some case but user has still a workaround to navigate to previous page. Most of the browser have options of Back in context menu. Thus user can still right click on the page and click Back to go to previous page. We will shortly see the workaround for this issue also.

Following is the code to open webpage in a new window have no toolbar (Back/Next buttons).

```
window.open ("http://viralpatel.net/blogs/",
"mywindow","status=1,toolbar=0");
```

Also it is possible to disable the right click on any webpage using Javascript. Add following code in the webpage.

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

**Disable Back functionality using history.forward**

This is another technique to disable the back functionality in any webpage. We can disable the back navigation by adding following code in the webpage. Now the catch here is that you have to add this code in all the pages where you want to avoid user to get back from previous page. For example user follows the navigation page1 -> page2. And you want to stop user from page2 to go back to page1. In this case all following code in page1.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```

The above code will trigger history.forward event for page1. Thus if user presses Back button on page2, he will be sent to page1. But the history.forward code on page1 pushes the user back to page2. Thus user will not be able to go back from page1.

**Warn User if Back is Pressed**

You may want to warn user if Back button is pressed. This works in most of the cases. If you have some unsaved form data, you might want to trigger a warning message to user if Back button is pressed.

Following Javascript snippet will add a warning message in case Back button is pressed:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "You work will be lost.";
```

[Reference](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my question is not about just click on back button. It is about right click on back button or press and hold the back button which open a drop down menu to select which page the user want to go back. I want to prevent to do this or remove these pages/my pages from the list.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { window.history.forward(1); };
```

or if u like to warning user

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Back button is not available!"; window.history.forward(1); };
```